# Нужна помощь с реализацией кляксы (жидкости)

Tags: svg, canvas, pixijs

Всем доброго времени, нужно реализовать анимацию (кляксы) как на данном сайте http://www.pixijs.com/. http://prntscr.com/kvdnpa

Вот моя клякса http://prntscr.com/kvcuwf

Подскажите, пожалуйста с алгоритмом.

Comment: Не нашёл кляксу на данном сайте, зато данный сайт получит посещения.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kvdnpa

Comment: там нету кляксы

Comment: Никита Фаст  http://prntscr.com/kvdnpa